# Setting EventTrigger with UnityScript

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, runtime, unityscript

I'm currently trying to add `onClick` methods to a button created at runtime. I have tried searching but can only find C# examples. Could anyone help me or direct me as to how I would go about this using UnityScript?

The following code is the button I have made:

```
GUI.Button(new Rect(280, 240, 50, 30), items[1]);
```

I have tried using the C# examples but they just created errors so I haven't included my attempts.